# How to get a list of all refs a git push would push?

Tags: git, git-push, git-filter-branch, git-remote

We're trying to implement a git workflow where there exists a pre-receive hook on the remote repo to validate that all pushed refs have commit messages that contain certain required information. In order to provide some convenience to developers, we'd also like a local git command developers can run to see what all refs would be pushed by a push command so they can verify before pushing whether or not their push would pass the hook, and also create a new git command that calls filter-branch or something else to rewrite all the commit messages to fill in any missing information.

So, is it possible to get a list of everything that would be pushed by a push command? `git push --dry-run --verbose` only gives a very cursory summary:

For example,

```
> git push --dry-run --verbose origin head:test/me

Pushing to git@git.mycompany.com:myproject.git
To git@git.mycompany.com:myproject.git
 * [new branch]      head -> test/me
```

Comment: You told it explicitly to push HEAD to test/me, and in return it told you that it would create a new branch on the server named test/me. What's cursory about that?

Comment: @Kevin I want to know the complete list of commits that it is going to transmit to the remote repository, either as a list of hashes or via the foo..bar syntax.

Comment: How many refs would a git push push if a git push did push refs?

Comment: You asked for refs, not a list of commits.

Comment: What I asked for was "a list of everything that would be pushed by a push command"

Answer (score 2):

```
git log @{u}..
```

This will list all the commits that are not yet pushed to the remote. If you want the diff of each commit then add a -p after log

```
git log -p @{u}..
```

Yes, the two dots at the end are necessary. :)

Comment: This sounds promising, but what is @{u} supposed to be? When I run this I get `error: No upstream branch found for ''
error: No upstream branch found for ''
error: No upstream branch found for ''
fatal: ambiguous argument '@{u}..': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions`

Comment: @nohat This reply comes very late, but here it is nevertheless: @{u} is a short form for @{upstream} which is a pointer to the tip of the remote-tracking branch which the current branch is tracking. The error you see is because of a missing mapping between your currently active branch and its remote-tracking branch. Run `git branch --set-upstream <branch-name> <remote-name>/<branch-name>` to set up the mapping. If `test` is the branch and `origin` is the remote then `git branch --set-upstream test origin/test` will set up the mapping. Also, I would be happy if you withdraw the -ve score.

Comment: Nice to know that shortcut! `git cherry -v @{u}` can do it also.

Answer (score 0):

You can use git push --porcelain.